# Handling Random Id Storage

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, database-design, architecture

Let's say we have an application like YouTube and we want to assign IDs to videos in a random way so that users can't iterate through the videos. E.g.      `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o4f5G9q_9O4`

I searched for solutions on this, but everywhere says that non-sequential ids will hurt indexing badly and that using incrementing ids and exposing them is not secure(and I agree).

How should this ids be stored? Will the ids not being sequential hurt indexing?

PS: I'm using MySQL to store this data

Comment: Your biggest concern would be preforming a [full table scan](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/table-scan-avoidance.html), which, if you have a proper index and query statements, you will not do. UUIDs do not (need) to be sequential, AFAIK. Following the details of the linked page, try to run a few queires and have MySQL _EXPLAIN_ what it is doing for each.

Answer (score 2):

The random string doesn't have to be the primary key. You can have an `AUTO_INCREMENT` primary key, which is used as the foreign key in other tables. In addition you can have a `unique_id` column that contains the random string that you expose in URLs. This can have a unique index on it, which will make lookups efficient.

This is analogous to a user table, where you might have a sequential `user_id`, and also a unique `user_name` column that's used for logging in, sending messages, displaying in posts, etc.

For the `unique_id` column, you'd ideally like to use a hash index rather than a B-tree index. Unfortunately, in MySQL this is only available in the `MEMORY` storage engine, not `InnoDB` or `MyISAM`.

Comment: But indexing random values can be a problem: https://blog.jcole.us/2014/10/02/visualizing-the-impact-of-ordered-vs-random-index-insertion-in-innodb/

Comment: @LucasPiske It's not as efficient as indexing structured data, but if you need a random string, what choice do you have?

Comment: In other words, if you have a choice between ordered and unordered data, use ordered data. But for applications like this, you don't have that choice.

Comment: I'm looking for different options. I thought I was maybe letting some ideas pass through my head.

Comment: Youtube is probably not using MySQL. They're probably using a database that has more flexible indexing mode, such as a hashed index for the unique string.

Comment: "Youtube uses MySQL database with sharding to handle lots of records."

Comment: Yes, they use MySQL as there primary data store. But they maybe could use some key-value store that maps the public random string to the internal auto-increment id. And key-value stores don't have the indexing problem. I also thought about doing this, but increases complexity and adds a "join".

Answer (score 0):

The discussion so far is about how bad UUIDs are.  Though I agree, I don't think it applies here.

Your situation is:  Given *one* random-looking id, fetch the *one* record that it refers to.  Correct?  You are not worrying about fetching several 'consecutive' records.

Generating the random key:  UUIDs are rather bulky; you might want something shorter.  Take `MD5()` of some unique string - perhaps the `AUTO_INCREMENT` id concatenated with a secret seed.  Then convert to base64 so that it won't be too long.  (Caveat:  watch out for special characters that could mess up a url).

Fetching:  Using that key as the `PRIMARY KEY` or a `UNIQUE` key will cost something in the way of randomness.  But I suspect it will be only a small percentage of the overhead in your app.

Answer (score -1):

1. Make up a random string.
2. Attempt to insert into a column with a `UNIQUE` constraint.
3. If it inserts, congratulations the identifier is yours.
4. If it fails as a duplicate, go back to step 1.

If you have a sufficiently long string and a sufficiently robust random number generator then collisions should be rare. If you use all letters (capital/lower-case) and numbers, then you can get away with ~20 character tokens that are very unlikely to collide.

Shorter keys work, but collisions will be more frequent. Test it yourself by generating a few million keys to see how many retries, on average, you'll need.

Comment: I thought about doing that, but I read  many articles on how non-sequential keys(UUID,Random Strings, etc) can hurt you in the long run. Because of the way B-Tree indexes work.

Comment: https://blog.jcole.us/2014/10/02/visualizing-the-impact-of-ordered-vs-random-index-insertion-in-innodb/

Comment: Unless you have *measurable* performance problems, don't stress out about it. This will be a problem at YouTube scale, but not with fewer than a billion records.